# Notation Question: If the diameter of $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is bounded, then $sup_{x,y \in X}||x-y||_2 \leq D_{2}$, what is $D_2$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

In reading the paper *Adaptive Subgradient Methods for
Online Learning and Stochastic Optimization* [here](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume12/duchi11a/duchi11a.pdf) on page 4, bottom of the page,

I am coming across some notation I am not familiar with, and with which a google search has not yielded any results.

The author writes:
If the diameter of $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is bounded, then $sup_{x,y \in X}||x-y||_2 \leq D_{2}$. Later the author uses the notation $D_{\infty}$ in a similar vain.

I am imagining this is somehow related to the $L^p$ norms, but am unsure how. One definition of the diameter of a set is in the context of a metric space $X$,

> $diam(X) := \sup d(x,y)$ for $ \forall x,y \in X$.

Any insights what $D_p$ means appreciated.

Comment: It appears that $D_2$ is the diameter of $X$ in the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm, and $D_\infty$ is the diameter of $X$ in the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. See p. $5$, where they say that for the set $\{x:\|x\|_{\infty}\le 1\}$, $D_2=2\sqrt{d}$, while $D_\infty=2$ (where we’re working in $\Bbb R^d$).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott right that makes the most sense. Embarrassed I didn't see that earlier, if you write this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Done! (I wasn’t entirely sure at first either, since they seemed to say that the diameter was less than or equal to the appropriate $D$, but that bit on p. $5$ was pretty clear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that $D_2$ is the diameter of $X$ in the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm, and $D_\infty$ is the diameter of $X$ in the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. See page $5$, where they say that for the set $\{x:\|x\|_\infty\le 1\}$, $D_2=2\sqrt{d}$, while $D_\infty=2$ (where we’re working in $\Bbb R^d$).